# Grep text only only after [word]:

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file example.txt which contains following text:

```
[one]: bla bla bla onebla twobla
[two]: hey heya noheya
[onemore]: i got mad and etc
```

I need to grep and show only text that after `[myword]:`

Tried to test `grep [myword] /tmp/example.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2`

On each `[myword]` it prints all after brackets, but how can I get only the one I need only and not all?

Comment: There is no `[myword]` in input

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to print only the test that after certain brackets. For example I want to print only text that in line `[one]:`  but not after `[two]:` or `[onemore]:`lines, so that the output will be `bla bla bla onebla twobla`. If I want to print all after `[onemore]:` - the correct output should be `i got mad and etc`

Answer (score 0):

You can cut the first phrase `[something]:` and get the rest using

**grep and sed:**

```
$ grep -w "\[onemore\]:" words.txt | sed 's/\[onemore\]://g'
 i got mad
```

**grep and awk:**

```
$ grep -w "\[onemore\]:" words.txt | awk -F: '{print $2}'
 i got mad
```

Comment: I need to get output of this for example:                                  'Grep [one more]:  words.txt'                                                                                   Result that I need to get:                                                               'I got mad'

Comment: @alya
whatever is your word/phrase add it into double quotes:

`grep -o -w "i got mad" words.txt`

Will result to: `i got mad`

Comment: @alya: I'm sorry for the last comment, wasn't looking exact grep input you posted.

I edited my answer to give you what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you @Kristo, but it doesn't work as needed. Please see my comment above.

Comment: @alya: I did read your comment and edited my post accordingly. If the edited solution doesn't work as needed please elaborate more how one of those the solution doesn't work exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all! Got an answer on other from Unix & Linux:

`$ awk '/\[myword\]/{sub(/^[^]]*\]:[[:blank:]]*/,"");print}' example.txt`

OR

`$ awk '/\[myword\]/{sub(/^[^]]*\]:[[:blank:]]*/,"");print}' example.txt`